# QGIS server service file pg_service.conf not found when doing a request

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-server, docker

Having this docker compose (v2) file for setting up a local (Ubuntu) QGIS server:

```sh
services:
  qgis:
    image: "camptocamp/qgis-server:latest"
    environment:
      PGSERVICEFILE: "/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf"
      QGIS_PROJECT_FILE: "/etc/qgisserver/foo/foos.qgs"
      QGIS_SERVER_LOG_LEVEL: 0
    volumes:
     - ./data:/etc/qgisserver
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

a valid QGIS server project file `./data/foo/foo.qgs` connecting to two samples layers in a local PostGIS database and this `./data/pg_service.conf` file:

```
[test]
  host=host.ip.address
  port=5432
  dbname=foo
  user=postgres
  password=****************
```

I'm facing this QGIS server error:

```sh
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 WARNING PostGIS[70]: Connection to database failed
test-qgis-1  | service file "/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf" not found
```

I don't know why, because the `$PGSERVICEFILE` variable is correctly set up and when I log into the container, I can successfully connect to the database using this pg service and the command: `psql -d service=test`.

Full request log:

```sh
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: ******************** New request ***************
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: Request URL: http://localhost:8080/qgis/wfs3
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: Environment:
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: ------------------------------------------------
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: SERVER_NAME: localhost
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: REQUEST_URI: /qgis/wfs3
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: SCRIPT_NAME: /qgis/wfs3
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: REMOTE_ADDR: 172.27.0.1
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: SERVER_PORT: 8080
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: QUERY_STRING: 
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: REQUEST_METHOD: GET
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: QGIS_PROJECT_FILE: /etc/qgisserver/foo/foo.qgs
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
test-qgis-1  | Headers:
test-qgis-1  | ------------------------------------------------
test-qgis-1  | "Accept" :  "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
test-qgis-1  | "Host" :  "localhost:8080"
test-qgis-1  | "User-Agent" :  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 WARNING PostGIS[70]: Connection to database failed
test-qgis-1  | service file "/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf" not found
test-qgis-1  | 
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 WARNING PostGIS[70]: Connection to database failed
test-qgis-1  | service file "/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf" not found
test-qgis-1  | 
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 CRITICAL Server[70]: Error, Layer(s) firstlayer_bfca477a_6cfb_4009_9f7a_e07afa052d65, secondlayer_809e7822_0380_4bbf_bd4b_68c94b210dc3 not valid in project /etc/qgisserver/foo/foo.qgs
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 WARNING Server[70]: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
test-qgis-1  | <ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException>
test-qgis-1  | 
test-qgis-1  | 09:10:21 INFO Server[70]: Request finished in 11 ms
test-qgis-1  | 853630 - 172.27.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2023:09:10:20 +0000] "GET /qgis/wfs3 HTTP/1.1" 500 310 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
```

Rights on the `pg_service.conf` file on the host and inside the container are as follow:

```sh
root@qgis-container:/etc/qgisserver# ls -lh pg_service.conf 
-rw------- 1 1000 1000 92 Nov 27 22:34 pg_service.conf
```

(Database version on the host is PostgreSQL 15.5 (Ubuntu 15.5-1.pgdg22.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit with PostGIS 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare that PGSERVICEFILE: "/etc/qgisserver/pg_service.conf"

And then you put the file here: ./data/pg_service.conf